# QObjectPicker not receiving hovering QMouseEvent in Qt3DWidget

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling, mouseevent, qt3d

I've implemented a [`Qt3DWidget`](https://github.com/florianblume/qt3d-widget) which works fairly well by letting Qt3D draw to an offscreen texture and using the texture's ID to draw on a quad in a `QOpenGLWidget`. The input source on the `QInputSettings` is set to `this`, i.e. the widget itself.

One issue that remains is that mouse hovering events (without clicking) are not properly processed and a `QObjectPicker` never fires its `moved` event when only hovering over an object. Clicking and dragging works on the other hand. For a couple of hours now I tried to track down where the event gets eaten - I'm sure this happens somewhere because clicking and moving emits the `moved` event. The latter indicates (in my view) that the event filter (a `PickEventFilter` - private Qt3D class) has been successfully installed. One failure case would have been that the event filter doesn't get installed.

Now I'm kind of stuck because it just seems impossible trying to figure out where the event dies. I've got the Qt debugging symbols and stepped through the code (which is sometimes a bit buggy because maybe due to code optimization). I figured out that the `PickEventFilter` gets the leaving event when moving the mouse by setting a breakpoint in this method:

```cpp
bool PickEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(obj);
    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
    case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
    case QEvent::MouseMove: {
        QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
        m_pendingMouseEvents.push_back({obj, QMouseEvent(*static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(e))});
    } break;
    case QEvent::HoverMove: {
        QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
        QHoverEvent *he = static_cast<QHoverEvent *>(e);
        m_pendingMouseEvents.push_back({obj, QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseMove,
                                                   he->pos(), Qt::NoButton, Qt::NoButton,
                                                   he->modifiers())});
    } break;
    case QEvent::KeyPress:
    case QEvent::KeyRelease: {
        QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);
        m_pendingKeyEvents.push_back(QKeyEvent(*static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(e)));
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And also on this line in `QWidgetWindow`:

```
    QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(receiver, &translated, widget, m_widget,
                                        &qt_button_down, qt_last_mouse_receiver);
```

When `sendMouseEvent` sends the moving event it never reaches the event filter. The only thing that arrives is a leave event. When you use `createWindowContainer` and `Qt3DWindow` the mouse events work. I really don't know what the difference is.

I don't think it's feasible to post code related to this issue but I'd hope that some of you can provide some ideas what to try out.

Comment: Stupid question: Are you aware of the [mouseTracking property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop)? You may have to enable this for your `QOpenGLWidget` to receive the hover events (aka. `mouseMoveEvent()`s). (This is mentioned in [QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent): _If mouse tracking is switched off, mouse move events only occur if a mouse button is pressed while the mouse is being moved. If mouse tracking is switched on, mouse move events occur even if no mouse button is pressed._)

Comment: Wow, you cannot imagine how dumb I feel right now. That was the issue! Thank you so much I could have spent another couple of hours until figuring this out. Could you post this as the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I enjoy being been of help but I somehow don't feel worth this an answer. ;-) However, this is situation I've found myself in more than once: to desperate looking into a complicated, just finished piece of code while partly being proud, partly scared whether it will work - and not seeing the stupid issue which was overlooked...

Comment: Hehe ok, I'll post an answer though for the sake of completeness. Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Scheff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478597/scheff) in the comments I was able to make it work by setting `setMouseTracking` in the `QWidget` class to true. This was blocking the hovering events.